# semantic release action not working as expected (not updating version)

Tags: github, github-actions

I have this action/workflow on github (2 sequential jobs the second one needs the first one to be completed and successful):

```
name: Release
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
jobs:
  release:
    name: Release
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: 16
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: npm ci
      - name: Release
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GH_TOKEN }}
          NPM_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.NPM_TOKEN }}
        run: npx semantic-release
  publish-npm:
    needs: release
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: 16
          registry-url: https://registry.npmjs.org/
      - run: npm publish
        env:
          NODE_AUTH_TOKEN: ${{secrets.NPM_TOKEN}}
```

They both run but the npm release isn't done bc the semantic release is not updating the version.

Where am I wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem by inspecting the actions on github. Funnily, the one that causes the problem is with a checkmark, this is the Release in my case:

> [1:15:54 PM] [semantic-release] › ℹ  This test run was triggered on the branch main, while semantic-release is configured to only publish from master, therefore a new version won’t be published.

So I configured semantic release to also do it on main branch. Just as easy as adding this to the **package.json**:

```
 "release":{ "branches": [ "master", "main" ] }
```